# circleCI's automated tests output an error that the table does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci

I use ruby on rails.I'm using circleCI to run automated tests, and when I implemented a test code that I hadn't implemented before, and tried to run it with circleCI, I got the following error: table doesn't exist.
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'saving_test-1.patienecs' doesn't exist.`

The configuration file is set up as follows, but how can I modify it to make the automated tests succeed?

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1

development:
  <<: *default
  database: saving_development

test:
  database: saving_test
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  host: 127.0.0.1

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DATABASE'] %>
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  charset: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

.circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@0.1.2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:3.0.0
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: test
    working_directory: ~/saving
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          name: restore result bundle install
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: bundle install
          command: bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs 4 --retry 3
      - run:
          name: rubocop
          command: bundle exec rubocop
      - save_cache:
          name: save cash result bundle install
          paths:
            - ./vendor/bundle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:3.0.0
        environment:
          - BUNDLER_VERSION: 2.1.4
          - RAILS_ENV: 'test'
          - DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
          - MYSQL_DB: saving_test
    working_directory: ~/saving
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: wait for database
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://127.0.0.1:3306 -timeout 5m

      - restore_cache:
          name: restore cash result bundle install
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
            bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs 4 --retry 3

      - run:
          name: Database Setup
          command: |
            bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
            bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
            bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

      - run:
          name: Run test
          command: bundle exec rails test


  deploy:
    machine:
      enabled: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - 34:98:98:c5:83:2a:c0:b1:94:a0:c2:56:2d:4c:0d:11
            - 08:a1:85:27:e7:83:c5:ae:68:8c:d2:3b:05:dc:82:70
      - run:
          name: Reflect Code
          command: ssh ${USER_NAME}@${HOST_NAME} 'cd /saving && sudo git pull origin main'
      - run:
          name: Docker task
          command: ssh ${USER_NAME}@${HOST_NAME} 'cd /saving && docker-compose down && docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d'
      - run:
          name: database setup
          command: ssh ${USER_NAME}@${HOST_NAME} 'cd /saving && docker-compose exec -T app rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production'

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_test_and_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - test
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

Patience

```
class Patience < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :memo,length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

#### Supplement

In database.yml and circleci's config.yml, I don't specify any table like saving_test-1.patiences with -1, so I don't even know why this 1 came up.

Comment: ActiveRecord assumes any activerecord class will have a corresponding table with the same name (except pluralized) and runs a query against that table when the class is loaded in order to load the columns. If that table doesn't exist, you'd get an error like what you're sharing. I'd look for an ActiveRecord class called 'Patience' in your codebase. Loading the file with this class definition locally should reproduce the error.

Comment: Umm... How can I do ??

Comment: Search your codebase for the string “class Patience”

Comment: I have searched and written code!

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'saving_test-1.patienecs' doesn't exist.` is likely due to a typo in your class name (which it looks like you've fixed).

Activerecord expects there to be a database table named `activerecord_subclass.name.underscore.pluralize`. So your `Patience` class needs a table named `patiences`. `saving_test-1` is the schema name for the database that circle-ci creates.

Assuming you have migrations / an up to date schema file that includes a `patiences` table, all you need to do is push the code to cirle-ci that you have here (`class Patience` not `class Patienec`) and you shouldn't see that error.

Comment: thank you! But, I have already been pushed, and it has been confirmed that the correct one is pushed on github as well.